# Random walk on hypercube : probabillity to stay at the same vertex is $1/2$

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $G$ be a hypercube and let $x = (x_1, .. , x_n)$ be the binary represantation of node $x$. We say that there exists an edge $(x,y)$ iff $x$ and $y$ differ only at one bit.
"We consider the following Markov chain defined on the n-cube. At each step, choose a coordinate i uniformly at random from $\{1, \ldots ,n\}$. The new state $y$ is obtained from the
current state $x$ by keeping all coordinates of $x$ the same, except possibly for $x_i$. The coordinate $x_i$ is set to zero with probability $1/2$ and to one with probability $1/2$. This Markov chain is exactly the random walk on the hypercube, **except that with probability $1/2$
the chain stays at the same vertex instead of moving to a new one**.."

*Τhis is from a book called "Probabillity and Computing"*

**My question** : I don't get why we stay at the same vertex with probabillity $1/2$. Let $x$ be a node: $x$ has $n$ bits and if we change exactly one of them we will reach one connected node. Therefore, **every node has $n$ neighbors**. So how can we stay at the same vertex ?

Comment: You have not read the instruction carefully: it explicitly says that with probability $1/2$ you don't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v=(v_1,v_2,\ldots ,v_n)$ one of the vertex of the hypercube, then the text says that the probability to choose some $k\in \{1,\ldots ,n\}$ is uniformly, that is, it is $\frac1{n}$, and once you choose a coordinate the probability that the new vertex is the same is $\frac1{2}$.

As this can happen with any chosen coordinate $k$ then the probability to stay in the same vertex is $\frac1{2}$ as, using the law of total probability, we have that

$$
\Pr [X_{m+1}=v|X_m=v]=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\Pr [X_{m+1}=v|X_m=v,C=k]\Pr [C=k]=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{2}\cdot \frac1{n}=\frac1{2}
$$

where $C$ is a r.v. uniformly distributed in $\{1,\ldots ,n\}$ and $X_m$ is a r.v. that represent the $m$-th step in the hypercube (the random walk is the stochastic process $\{X_m\}_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$).